# Get data for multiple circle diagrams in a smart way thorugh SQL Query

Tags: mysql

**My current situation:**

I have a working solution to achieve data for my (currently 8) circle diagrams.

**My current SQL QUERY looks like this:**

```
$querybar1 = "
select *, hours_id, sum(user_hours * 100 / $total) as 'totalsum1'
from hours
where projecthours_id = $id
and hours_type = '1'
group by hours_type
";
```

I then run 8 simular ones with different hours_type = (1-8), $querybar(1-8) and as 'totalsum(1-8)'.

The database structure:

```
hours_id = Primary id for each entry
projecthours_id = The ID of the project
userhours_id = The ID of the user who added data
user_hours = Amount of hours added
hours_type = Type of the hours added, for example: Inbox, Production..

#hours
hours_id  projecthours_id  userhours_id  user_hours  hours_type
1         14               2             5           1
```

**The problem:**

It's possible for the users to add new diagrams through PHP -> SQL, but my current PHP code is not adapted to that situation. So for example if a user adds a new circle diagram, my PHP code that echos the query will handle it and list another circle diagram next to the earlier ones, BUT it won't read out the % data to the new circle diagram since it dosn't have any data for that one, other than the SQL Querys that I've manually made in the code.

**Requested solution:**

I need to automate this so that it dosn't run one query for each and every single one of the circle diagrams. So that I for example, when adding another circle diagram later on, don't manually need to set up a SQL Query in the code that achieves the circle diagram data.

Any idéas on how to make this smarter?

Comment: Use conditional aggregation , eg: COUNT() with IF() / CASE WHEN statements

Comment: Any time you find yourself with `*` and `GROUP BY` in the same query, you can be certain that something has gone very wrong somewhere.